# Time series analysis with spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, nosql, time-series, powerbi

I am working on a project which generates 40-50 Gbs of time series data every day.

```
Phase   Time (UTC) Sensor   Voltage (Vrms)  Current (Arms)  Real Power (kW) Reactive Power (kVAr)   

A   30/11/2017 0:00 1   242.049 94.7869 22.6874 3.4158  
B   30/11/2017 0:00 2   242.648 58.2347 13.9256 2.39754 
C   30/11/2017 0:00 3   243.448 74.8243 17.0897 6.30549 
A   30/11/2017 0:10 1   241.358 93.3049 22.2974 3.15765
```

We receive these data in form of flat files and will upload them into data lake using azure data factory.

throughout the process, the data need to be processed with spark and visualized with Power BI or any other visualization tool.

we could have random access + frequent concurrent queries which I heard is not suitable for Spark.

I am so confused to choose the best tools to create this pipeline. I might have two options :

**option 1 :**

1. Load data from CSV file
2. Cleaning the data
3. Write to qarquet file )
4. Load data from parquet file
5. Analyse it
6. pass to power BI

   **Option 2:**

   - Load data from CSV file
   - Cleaning the data
   - Write to any nosql or time series nosql database
   - Load data from db , Analyse it with sparksql or ?????
   - pass it to power BI

or any other options should be considered?

Comment: Why not utilize a TSDB which are optimized to handle time series data of this type? Also, when you say 40 GBs, I assume you're taking about CSV file size, how many time:value samples are there daily?

Comment: Well, in our case, we generating 1000 of csv files ( 1 to 10 mb) 1 to 10 GB in total every day.  because they are generated from many sources. plus a big historical data. So, the ingestion looks like as follow:

1. Ingesting a flat file (big size) in the bigdata database.
2. Ingesting a huge amount of files 

 we will end up with 10's or 100's of TBs of data and I feel that NoSQL or time series NoSQL could help us to effectively visualise the data.

Please be aware this should be done like real time analytics as end users only have knowledge of Power BI

Comment: PowerBI, by virtue of not supporting JDBC, eliminates almost all nosql bigdata solutions out there, unless you want to jump through ODBC>JDBC middleware.

Comment: can you please tell me what would be a possible solution here? after ingestion the flat files with Azure data factory and push it to Azure data lake store. since we will be dealing with 100 TBs of data, should we use spark and power bi? should we use time series nosql like openTSBD in the pipeline?

Comment: Using the above format, a 1MB CSV file contains 18724 rows, each with 4 samples each, so 74898 samples in total. This can be compressed by time series databases to 1.0 - 1.5 bytes per sample, or 73KB - 105KB per file. This equates to 90% compression. I would consider storing this data in a TSDB outright instead of a data lake which is geared more at merging disparate data sources and running M/R jobs.

Comment: That id great. ok let say we store the data in a TSDB like InfluxDB vs OpenTSDB, the question is whether it is reasonable to use spark to run pre-defined queries?

Comment: I have experience with Axibase TSD where you can query data using SQL syntax so no need for Spark just to retrieve time series in raw or processed format.